# A software program that provides a fake UPNP server

Tags: security, server, upnp

I want to have UPNP server that is incapable of doing anything, except logging. Since it is impossible to have a secure UPNP server.

1. Log request for modifications to the firewall. As much information about the request even if it might be fake.
2. Even better if it lies and says yes to every firewall request and does nothing.
3. bonus I can instruct it to say No to certain request in case yes causes problems.

If I have a program that wants/depends on UPNP in order to connect to the internet I can review the ports its requesting, and manually approve them elsewhere.  Also if rogue software gets installed it will probably try to utilize upnp to get open internet access, then I can find and remove it.

I would prefer a linux based solution.